# How should I build my home lab to study MCTS/MCITP/MCSE/MCSA?

Tags: untagged

I am trying to build a home lab to simulate real server and client environment.Care to give some suggestion?

virtualPC/Vmware/virtualbox

or real physical PC

Answer (score 2):

If you were to buy a middle of the road PC from any decent computer maker, beef it up with 4GB of RAM (or 8GB if you can afford it), you'll have a pretty decent lab right there. I used to have piles of hardware around the house but today my home lab is a single box like this. I probably have more than 50 virtual machines on that computer but rarely need to run more than a dozen at a time. Because this lab is intended to simulate configuration only, when I create VMs I usually only give them 512MB or 1GB of RAM. For a lab where you're trying to work on configurations, this works great.

As for which virtualization solution you choose to run, that's your choice. I'd recommend VMWare or Hyper-V as they are the most popular options in the Microsoft world.